# Aquamacs: Display *Occur* in current frame

Tags: frames, aquamacs, occur, dedicated-windows

I find that if I run `*Occur*` on different virtual displays, Aquamacs will reuse whichever frame `*Occur*` ran in the previous time, often giving me the results I want to see on a display which I am not currently looking at.

I could find nothing in https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AquamacsEmacsCompatibilitySettings about changing this back to the normal sane behavior, and I don't really understand how the "dedicated window" logic works, or whether that's what at play here. I have already implemented most of the other tweaks to get a "normal" Emacs, including setting `one-buffer-one-frame-mode` to `nil`.

In simple terms, how can I make sure the `*Occur*` buffer is displayed in the frame which is currently active, where I just ran `M-x occur`?

There are other functions which behave the same in Aquamacs, too; a general solution which turns off this buffer window reuse would be much preferred. For example, I often (but not always) see this with `*vc-log*` for getting diffs for a version-controlled file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aquamacs is a version of GNU Emacs configured to behave in a more OSX way like TextEdit. This means that each  thing is in a separate OS Window. Later versions of Aquamacs and macOS have added tabs so things can open in a new tab.

Thus Aquamacs is behaving as designed.

You can limit the number of new OS Windows/Emacs frames that are opened by customising the One Buffer One Frame Mode to nil (note just setting it won't work). Aquamacs will open new things in the current frame.

However if you have already opened `*Occurs*` in one frame and then call it from another then Aquamacs will open the `*Occurs*` buffer in the frame it was already in and not your current frame.

I get annoyed with this as you are and now run Aquamacs as one Emacs Frame/OS Window, a sort of halfway house. That is I very rarely use the new frame command e.g. <kbd>⌘N</kbd> or <kbd>⌘T</kbd>

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to accept. Eventually I gave up on Aquamacs and switched to https://emacsforosx.com/

Comment: I have done the same as Aquamacs has not been update past emacs 25 I now have a long init.el to give the same behaviour